# How do I get the Outlook.MailItem from a new Compose window?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am trying to capture the `MailItem` object from my Add-In. I tried looking in the `Globals.FormRegions` but didn't really get anywhere. Any clue how to access the `Outlook.MailItem` in a new Compose window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`ActiveInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx) to access the `MailItem`. **Inspectors** are the windows which display individual Outlook items. [`Inspector.CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722.aspx) returns the Outlook item currently being displayed in the inspector window.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
```

Comment: This worked. The route I ended up choosing was to take control of the ItemSend event for the application and then access the mail item that way. However this did answer my question!